# SAPUI5: Binding Context of view doesn't get unbinded

Tags: json, sapui5

I am developing in SAPUI5 and bind a JSON Model Context against a create entity view. This is my binding (Info: I am using a JSON model to bind against):

```
var oContext = new sap.ui.model.Context(
                   this.oEntitiesModel,
                   "/EntitySet/" + iNextEntryInEntitySet);
this.getView().setBindingContext(oContext);
```

However after I successfully create my new entity I'm navigating to the new entity. If I now want to create another entity the values which I submitted in the create entity view are still there. 
I already tried many things like `this.getView().unbindContext();`or `this.getView().unbindObject();` or `this.getView().unbindElement();`

All these functions did not lead to a fresh create view.
However, the binding context get's updated, because I am able to create another new entity out of this.
Is there another possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call [invalidate](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#invalidate) method on your form or view.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but it's still not working. Also the "onInit" Method doesn't get called when I want to add another entity. Is there a possibility to "destroy" the view so the "onInit" Method gets called every time?

Comment: "onInit" gets called only once the controller instance gets created; during the further "enterings" of the screen, the same instance is reused, that's why it doesn't get called the second times.. However it is strange that "unbindObject" with "invalidate" does not work. Do you use named model? if so the "unbindObject" should be called with the model's name as a parameter.

Comment: Yes I have a named model. Thanks for the tip with the model's name as parameter, but still don't work. I'm assuming that it got nothing to do with the binding of the view. But still thanks a lot for your suggestions!